# Launching SweetAlert to prevent user from closing window

Tags: javascript, jquery, sweetalert

I am trying to display a message to the user before he closes the window. I am using SweetAlert (http://tristanedwards.me/sweetalert) which is running fine.

The problem is with the JavaScript/jQuery to let me know when the user is trying to close the window/tab and then to display something preventing him from closing the page unless he clicks again.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
    window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
    function confirmExit() {
        swal("Here's a message!");
        return "You have attempted to leave this page. Are you sure?";
    }
</script>
```

I have tried this, but it displays the ugly usual message on top of my SweetAlert, any ideas?
Without the return part it closes the window anyway, I tried :/

Comment: can you show it working on your website? just by this code snippet its going to be tough to figure out the problem.

Comment: I think it's browser default so there's no way to prevent the default alert from being displayed when the user tries to close the browser.

Comment: try using `return ;` instead of the current one you're using

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[You can't disable the alert, nor change the style of the alert on `onbeforeunload`.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/276660/how-can-i-override-the-onbeforeunload-dialog-and-replace-it-with-my-own) The main reason is for security problems.

From MDN document, [WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload), it says,

> When this event returns a non-void value, the user is prompted to confirm the page unload. In most browsers, the return value of the event is displayed in this dialog. In Firefox 4 and later the returned string is not displayed to the user. Instead, Firefox displays the string "This page is asking you to confirm that you want to leave - data you have entered may not be saved." See bug 588292.
>
> Since 25 May 2011, the HTML5 specification states that calls to window.alert(), window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during this event. See the HTML5 specification for more details.
>
> Note also that various mobile browsers ignore the result of the event (that is, they do not ask the user for confirmation). Firefox has a hidden preference in about:config to do the same. In essence this means the user always confirms that the document may be unloaded.